# How to download all Facebook 'posts to page' (without scrolling)

Tags: ajax, facebook, web

I would like to be able to download/take a copy of all Posts from a Facebook page.
Typically only a few posts are loaded, then as you scroll to the bottom it loads more.

Is there a way to trigger the loading of all posts?

example page: 
https://www.facebook.com/orgranhealthandnutrition/posts_to_page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scraping is not allowed, you MUST use the Graph API to do that. You will most likely want to use the `/page-id/posts` endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

You only need an App Access Token for that, which is easy to create: `App-ID|App-Secret`

Careful though, don´t use that one on the client, because the App Secret should only be used on the server. It´s called "Secret" for a reason.

Test it in the API Explorer, there is a "paging" object with "next" in it. You can iterate with that one.